# comp runs like its stuck in a windows update

Tags: 18.04

New at this and not sure how to ask this accurately/succinctly. Occasionally my machine runs like an old windows box stuck in an update. The mouse hangs, doesn’t respond to movement or clicks, or the pointer disappears. Is there a way I can monitor activity to see what’s hogging resources? Is that even the right approach?
running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
machine is a Dell SFF from about 2013. i5 2400 quad core 4gb ram 250gb hdd

Comment: One of the easy ways is to type  top  in terminal.  System monitor is also a way(found in activities), but tends to use more resources.  Sounds like a program is acting up.

Comment: How much swap does `free -h` say you have? Just after the system comes back, `journalctl --since="-5 minutes"` will show you system logs.

Comment: @waltinator  apologies about the formatting  Mem:  total    3.7G   used   2.4G   free   407M                       
Swap: total    3.9G   used   2.1G   free   1.8G     shared:336M   buff/cache:911M   available:756M